# How higher load (high R) draws more current when the nature of resistance is to reduce/restrict the current?

Tags: voltage, current, resistance, load

Consider a voltage in a circuit(say 100 V) in a closed circuit, and a resistor 10 ohm and a Load of 20 ohm connected across it.
when you turn on the switch, current through them is almost 100/30 (3.33~ A).
but when you increase the Load (say instead of 20 ohm, 40 ohm, the current now is 2 A.

but usually when the Load increases, we say it draws more current. how??

Comment: you increased the resistance ... that is a decreased load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but usually when the Load increases, we say it draws more current. how??

"Increasing the load" thing sometimes creates this kind of confusion. I believe this is where the difference between "load" and "loading" becomes more apparent **(*)**.

- If you say "increase the load" then I'll "increase" the load resistance *(decrease the loading)*.
- If you say "increase the **loading**" then I'll "decrease" the load *(load resistance)* to push the supply further i.e. increase the load current  / loading *(i.e. the burden on its shoulders)*.

I prefer to be more specific and clear i.e. I use "increase load resistance" or "increase loading".

<sup>**(*)** My native language is not English.</sup>

Comment: can you please tell me the difference between Load and Loading? I don't understand how the resistance decreases when you increase loading. it seems counter-intuitive.

Comment: @Fredrick loading in Amps or Watts or percentage (nominal), load in Ohms. Increase the load, increase the load "resistance". Increase the loading, increase the output current or output power in general (e.g. decrease load resistance). Though I see both terms are used interchangeably which I don't find correct.